# Двигающееся и масштабируемое изображение на сайте

Tags: javascript, html

Вот в чем проблема. Хочу сделать сайт с картой, которая будет приближаться и отдаляться при прокрутке колесика мыши и двигаться влево-вправо-вверх-вниз при движении нажатой мыши в соответствующие стороны. Причем при клике мышкой на карте по населенным пунктам, они выделяются.

Проблема возникает, во-первых, *при масштабировании* (приближении и отдалении карты), как его сделать? Всегда отображать одно и то же изображение при увеличении и уменьшении или отображать разные изображения (каждое для определенного масштаба)?

Во-вторых, так как мне нужно отмечать населенные пункты, на которых была нажата мышка, требуется *получать координаты мыши относительно левого верхнего края изображения*. Как это делать, если помещать изображение в hmtl-код через тег ?

Answer (score 0):

Лучше не мучайтесь и воспользуйтесь api [яндекс карт](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/quick-start/tasks/quick-start-docpage?from=jsapi) или [гугл карт](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/?hl=ru).

Comment: спасибо конечно за ответ. Но хотелось бы помучаться и сделать карту без апи яндекса или гугла. Просто интересно изобрести свой велосипед, никому от этого хуже не станет, проект-то не в продакшн. @Darth